# What does "denial was the route" mean?

Tags: meaning

In [Runaway Jury (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_Jury), after unsuccessful cross examination, a defendant confronts their attorney:

> Attorney: We've got damage-control strategies, and your testimony
> before cross was strong.
>
> Defendant: Oh, you, you! I mean, you are the one that told me **denial
> was the route** to take here. I was improperly prepped.
>
> Attorney: Look--
>
> Defendant: You, get out of here.

What does "denial was the route" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here "route" is being used in the sense of "path or course". The defendant is saying that he was advised to deny whatever the events under discussion were.